# Distribution of uniform-normed random vector

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

What is the pdf of $\vec{Y} = \frac{\vec{X} }{\lVert \vec{X} \rVert_\infty}$ with $\vec{X}$ a random vector following a multivariate standard normal distribution (zero-mean $\vec{\mu} = 0$ and covariance-matrix $\Sigma = I$ ($I$ denotes identity matrix))?

$\lVert \vec{X} \rVert_\infty$ denotes the uniform-norm with $\lVert \vec{X} \rVert_\infty = \max(\lvert X_1 \rvert,...\lvert X_n \rvert,...\lvert X_N \rvert)$ with $X_n$ the $n$th entry of vector $\vec{X} \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: Choose a point uniformly on the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^N$ and inflate it until its $L^\infty$ norm is 1. 

Comment: What do you mean by "inflate"?

Comment: Multiply it by a constant. (specifically, one over its $L^\infty$ norm)

Comment: Thanks, but how do I infer the pdf from that "inflation"?

Comment: Just think of how a small piece on the cube boundary is projected to the unit sphere (the Jacobian is just the cosine of the angle between the radius-vector and the coordinate direction determining the current face of the cube divided by the length of the vector to the power $n-1$. Normalize it properly and here is your pdf).

Comment: Fedja, I really don't understand what you are proposing I should do. How do I infer from the Jacobian to the PDF? Do you suggest using a random variable transformation? And why is the Jacobian the cosine of the angle ...?

Comment: Draw a 2D picture. You need a distribution on the boundary of the square that, after projecting to the unit circle, becomes a uniform distribution on the circle. Assume that your pdf is $f$. Note that if you have a small interval on the side of the square around a point $x$, then the image on the circle is a small arc, so $f(x)$ must be approximately the ratio of the length of that arc divided by $2\pi$ to the length of the interval. That should remind you of the general change of variable formula in the integral where the Jacobian is what you need. Is that much clear?

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I'm not sure which integral I should evaluate ... should I integrate over the boundary of the square over a small interval and letting this interval approach zero afterwards? This seems a little bit too complicated

Comment: OK, let's start with the basics then. The entire distribution is concentrated on the boundary of the square. So, your "probability density function" is actually a measure singular with respect to the 2-dim. Lebesgue measure but absolutely continuous with respect to the length measure on the boundary of the unit square and we have to talk about its density $f$ with respect to the length measure. Is that much clear? 